# Conditionally running a bash script in Makefile before compiling the source files

Tags: makefile

I have the Makefile as below

```
BASH_SCRIPT := xyz.sh

SOURCE_DIR = \
        src

.PHONY: all
all: $(SOURCE_DIR)

.PHONY: $(SOURCE_DIR)
$(SOURCE_DIR):
        @${BASH_SCRIPT} 
        @$(MAKE)
```

Now, If I want to run the bash script conditionally only if a file in another directory say 'source_dir2' changes, how can I do it? Any idea??

Comment: Wait... What do want this makefile to *do?* Why does the rule invoke recursive Make?

Comment: This is not a right Makefile yet. But the aim is to compile a set of source files in a directory and before that conditionally run a script depending on if the files in another directory got changed or not.

Comment: Got changed since when? Make compares the modification times of two files.

Comment: Got changed since last compilation. My aim is to run a script conditionally inside Makefile if a file is changed after previous compilation.